# Blur effect and other things not working in kde after restart

Tags: updates, kubuntu, kde

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but because I am using Kubuntu I decided to ask here.

My problem is that some applications, I have currently found two, have just stopped working after restarting. Yakuake and gnome system monitor, I have no idea what is special about those two except that I use them a lot. When I start them they are invisible, I don't know if they are doing anything. I have tried reinstalling yakuake but it didn't fix it. It has also made the blur effect disappear (And no it does not help turning that setting on and off to fix it). The only thing I have really done is update the computer, which took a while because I had forgotten to do it in a pretty long while.

My hardware is an intel core i3 (I don't know what generation, this is a school laptop and I don't know how to check) and I'm using the intel hd graphics gpu. I am also using an external display connected via display port (Though using a converter to HTMI for the display). I don't know how that can help, but I'd rather give too much information then too little.

Edit: The "Hamburger menu" and similar does not work either, such as the history button

inxi output:

```
System:    Host: markus-ThinkPad-X240 Kernel: 4.4.0-131-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.8.9 (Qt 5.6.1) dm: sddm,sddm Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 20AMS68500 v: ThinkPad X240 Chassis: type: 10
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20AMS68500 v: SDK0E50510 WIN Bios: LENOVO v: GIET76WW (2.26 ) date: 08/27/2014
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4030U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 7582
           clock speeds: min/max: 800/1900 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 800 MHz 3: 845 MHz 4: 854 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a16
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@59.99hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:9c20
           Card-2 Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a0c
           Card-3 Licensed by Sony Entertainment America driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 002-006 chip-ID: 12ba:0034
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-131-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I218-LM
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: 3080 bus-ID: 00:19.0 chip-ID: 8086:155a
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:08b2
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 158.8GB (22.6% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_THNSNJ12 size: 128.0GB serial: Z4NS10T3T8MW temp: 37C
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: Ultra size: 30.8GB serial: 4C530001301208116254-0:0 temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 34G used: 30G (94%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.97GB used: 0.15GB (4%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 3067
Info:      Processes: 243 Uptime: 48 min Memory: 1932.2/3643.0MB
           Init: systemd v: 229 runlevel: 5 default: 2 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (fish running in konsole) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: 1) Kubuntu is on-topic here. 2) Why do you have gnome system monitor? Kubuntu has the equivalent already installed: it is just "System Monitor" aka "KSysGuard". 3) If you can, install *inxi* using `sudo apt install inxi` and then run the command `inxi -Fxxxz` and post the output here using the edit option below your question. That'll tell us a lot about your system in a concise way.

Comment: I am using Gnome system monitor because that is what I have installed, KSysGuard is not installed. (This might be because I originally used normal Ubuntu, but I changed to KDE later on. I have uninstalled the ubuntu desktop environment though)

Comment: I am sorry, but the formating did not work in the post

Comment: Okay, so in a strict sense, you aren't using Kubuntu. What you have is a hybrid which may behave oddly because developers of a particular desktop environment probably focus on their own desktops :(

Comment: That might be true, I'll see if anything get's fixed after an update or two. If an update broke it, an update might fix it